# Is there a difference between the 2008 and 2009 namespace for Deep Zoom Images?

Tags: deepzoom, seadragon

I noticed that Deep Zoom Composer writes DZIs with a namespace of

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2009
```

However the official documentation and the only available schema refer to

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008
```

XML dictates I cannot treat them as equivalent, although they seem to be. So does anyone know if there is a difference and even better, can point to some documentation?

Comment: Is it possible they're typos? Are you able to download XSD schema definitions and diff them?

Comment: As I said, the only schema I could find is the 2008 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking with the program manager for Seadragon at that time, he believes the only thing that was added was an optional extra tag to support Microsoft's [Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming) server feature. If you're not using Smooth Streaming, the 2008 schema is identical to the 2009 one.

Comment: Kinda funny that you're ending up giving the answer which was just required for a patch to a project you now maintain ;)

Comment: @Joey I suppose so! Just trying to make sure the paper trail is complete. :-)